# Evaluating differential equations of reducible to homogenous form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My question is to solve this differential equation,
$$(3x-7y-3)dy=(3y-7x+7)dx$$
After evaluating to a certain level I get 
$$\frac57\log((y+x-1)/x-1)-\frac27\log((y-x+1)/x-1)=\log x+c$$
(where c is a const).I'm pretty sure the solution till this step is devoid of any errors.
But my book answer is $(y-x+1)^2(y+x-1)^5=k$(where k is a const.)
Can someone please tell the use of properties of logarithms to arrive at the answer with steps??

Comment: Yes .I have solved the question.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$(3x-7y-3)dy=(3y-7x+7)dx$$
The method to transform to an homogeneous ODE consists in a linear change of variables :
$\begin{cases}x=X+a\\y=Y+b \end{cases}\quad\to\quad (3x-7y-3+3a-7b)dY=(3y-7x+7+3b-7a)dX$

$\begin{cases}-3+3a-7b=0\\7+3b-7a=0 \end{cases}\quad\to\quad \begin{cases}a=1\\b=0 \end{cases}\quad\to\quad \frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{3Y-7X}{3X-7Y}$

This is an homogeneous ODE.

The method to transform to a separable ODE consists in the change of function :

$Y(X)=XF(X) \quad\to\quad \frac{dY}{dX}=F+X\frac{dF}{dX}=\frac{3F-7}{3-7F}$

$X\frac{dF}{dX}=\frac{3F-7}{3-7F}-F=\frac{7F^2-7}{3-7F} \quad\to\quad \frac{dX}{X}=\frac{3-7F}{7(F^2-1)}dF$
$$\ln|X|=\int \frac{3-7F}{7(F^2-1)}dF = -\frac{2}{7}\ln|F-1|-\frac{5}{7}\ln|F+1|+\text{constant}$$
$$X^7(F-1)^2(F+1)^5=C$$
$$X^7(\frac{Y}{X}-1)^2(\frac{Y}{X}+1)^5=C \quad\to\quad (Y-X)^2(Y+X)^5=C$$
$X=x-1$ and $Y=y$
$$(y-x+1)^2(y+x-1)^5=C$$